# On finite exponent abelian $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian $p$-group non-isomorphic to any group of the form $H\times K$ where $H$ and $K$ are nontrivial groups. And let $\{|a|\mid a\in G\}$ have an upper bound in $\Bbb N$ .  Is $G$ finitely generated?

Comment: Obviously you want $G$ to be infinite? Right?

Comment: Can't you just take the infinite elementary abelian group $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Z_p$?

Comment: @andybenji: sorry I forget to add the condition that it is not  product factorizible.

Comment: @B.S.: There is not such condition for $G$. But a counterexample (if any) has to be an infinite group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Theorem 17.2 in Fuchs' "Infinite Abelian Groups" (vol.1), the result is originally due to Prüfer and Baer:

**Theorem.** *A bounded Abelian group is a direct sum of cyclic groups.*

As a corollary you obtain that any indecomposable bounded Abelian group is cyclic.

Comment: By *bounded* do you mean *of finite exponent*?

Comment: Exactly, I mean that there is a common (finite) upper bound for the orders of the elements of the group.

Comment: which page is this theorem located?

Comment: page 88 in the edition of 1970. The idea of the proof is that any bounded group equals its basic subgroup, which is a direct sum of cyclics.

Comment: found: http://books.google.com/books?id=Vb38GspKia8C&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q&f=true. thanks.

Comment: @user1729: The exponent of a group $G$ is defined: $\operatorname{exp} G=\max\{|a|\mid a\in G\}$. So are  Prüfer groups of finte exponent?

Comment: @user1729 what do you mean by "finite but unbounded" ??? If the set of the orders of the elements is unbounded, then its sup (which by definition is the exponent of the group) is infinite. Of course the Prüfer groups do have infinite exponent, as they are unbounded.

Comment: @user138171 Sorry, I was getting "finite exponent" confused with "periodic". I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @user1729: I should replace $\max$ with $\sup$ in exponent definition. otherwise Prufer group will have no exponent

Comment: @user138171 But that is the point! They are periodic, but are not bounded (so do not have finite exponent). Changing max to sup won't change anything.

Comment: @user1729 the correct thing is to use "supremum" instead of maximum. Indeed, the set $\{p^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ does not have a maximum, but it does have a supremum (i.e., $\infty$). In fact, $\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$ has exponent, the fact is that it is not finite.

Comment: @Simone Some conventions dictate that a group of unbounded exponent has exponent zero...

Comment: I see, I never found this convention but it is not hard to believe that in some context this could be useful. What I found is a different definition for $p$-groups, if you have a $p$-group $G$ such that $\sup\{|g|:g\in G\}=p^k$ you say that $k$ is the exponent, while sometimes you take directly $p^k$. Of course these definitions produce the same classes of "groups with finite exponent".

Answer (score 1):

The answer would seem to be no. A finitely generated Abelian group is a direct product of finitely many cyclic groups (some of which may be infinite). In your situation, the cyclic factors would be of bounded order, so if your group were finitely generated, it would be finite (and even cyclic by the indecomposability condition you impose).

Later edit: In view of comments, yes, I overlooked one case. The group in question is either finite cyclic of prime power order (such a group is not a direct product of smaller proper cyclic subgroups), or it is infinitely generated.

Comment: If finitely generated then yes. But do you have an example for a group satisfying the conditions but not finitely generated (equivalently not finite or not cyclic)? This is the my question.

Comment: The answer is yes. because every cyclic and every finite group is finitely generated! except your definition for *finitely generated* excludes them.

Comment: Yes, I had overlooked the case of finite cyclic groups of prime power order. And yes, cyclic groups are finitely generated.